# Unexpected padding in <td> despite nothing in CSS making it this way

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a basic A4 document in `HTML` using mm `CSS` sizing. The document is sized perfectly - it prints fine on A4, covering virtually the full page, leaving a nice 3mm margin around it. I'm using a table for the layout, as the original document (that i'm re-creating in `HTML`) was created in `Excel`, and therefore has a table structure.

As I need the table to have an exact 3mm margin, i'm setting the width and height in mm, and using absolute positioning (3mm top and left). I had originally created the table-like layout using `div`s - but making the lines overlap perfectly using this is extremely fiddly - you can't really do it properly, as you're working with a mixture of millimetres and pixels, hence my choice for using a table.

The table displays perfectly, all rows uniformly fill the document. Some of the rows need to be split, so I chose to use floated divs within the s, within the s.

Despite resetting the `CSS`, and setting the `<tr>`s padding to 0, and the `<td>`s padding to 0, and giving the table `border-collapse: collapse;` and `border-spacing: 0;`, there's an annoying little margin between the `div`, that even Chrome can't explain why it's there:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qt1n54m9fxxl6f2/job_sheet_template.html

[image]

You may need to open the image link, and zoom in, to see the green highlighted space below the `div`s (which is apparently the `<td>`s padding). In the bottom, right hand corner, you can see that the padding isnt set?

Why is this here?

Comment: please paste your concerned css and html....difficult to state a reason without them!

Comment: Link to your page would help too.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qt1n54m9fxxl6f2/job_sheet_template.html

Answer (score 1):

Your image shows that border collapse isn't being applied. Try using:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
```

Comment: But I didn't see that you used??

Comment: @DanielPrice OP already used this as he said in question..read full question.

Comment: Your images shows that border-collapse isn't being applied... try to use !important.

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed the problem -

The padding isn't set, but somehow setting the divs height to 100% doesn't work - I've now set it to 5.4mm which fits perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

for html

```
html
{
    font-size:0;
}
```